# How to prevent other users, including root, from executing a given program?

Tags: linux, security, file-permissions, password-protection

In a Linux system such as Debian, how do I prevent an installed application from being used by other users, unless they enter a password? Other types of authentication tokens are acceptable, too.

I want to prevent other users, *including root*, from using an application that I have installed.

Comment: Sorry, but you're barely intelligible.

Comment: Yeah , maybe ^_^  - but still , its a good question - I think so.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense: In the first paragraph you say *"without password"* but in the second paragraph you say *"setup a password"*. You also say you want to protect from root access but dont care if root sees your password. These all seem contradictory and illogical. Please edit your question and try to express what you want more carefully.

Comment: Not it isn't illogical .  And it's make sesne for me. I want to create protection , but if root-user will broke it - it's dosen't matter, at least another users have some difficulties to do it :) .

Comment: @FrostysShad If you want help, it has to make sense *for everyone*. I made an attempt to extract your actual concern. Please verify that this is what you’re interested in.

Comment: Yeah thanx - it's more good then it's was. My English is so poor :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is ***still*** unclear.

1. If you want to “prevent an installed application from being used
   by other users” (other than yourself and `root`),
   just protect it 700 (or 500), as Jarmund’s answer says. 
   This won’t stop `root`, but you say,
   “if root user will [break] it – it doesn’t matter.” 
   I’m not clear on your position regarding “other users”. 
   You say, “I want to prevent other users …
   from using an application that I have installed.”  Does this mean

   - You don’t want *anybody* else to be able to run the program. 
     It’s OK if this is enforced by a password (which nobody but you would know).
   - You ***want*** selected other users to be able to run the program. 
     You are willing to authorize the selected users by telling them the password.
   - You ***want*** selected other users to be able to run the program. 
     You specifically want to authorize the selected users
     by telling them a password.

   ?

   If it’s the first bullet,
   it’s probably easiest to just `chmod` the executable
   and live with the fact that that `root` will be able
   to bypass that protection.
2. If it’s the second bullet, check whether your system has ACLs. 
   If it does, set up an access control list
   that allows only your chosen users to execute the file. 
   Of course this won’t stop `root` either.
3. If it’s the third bullet — you specifically want to use a password
   (or if denying access to `root` is really important to you) —
   encryption is the way to go. 
   Encrypt your executable with a password,
   delete the unencrypted program from the system,
   and tell the password to your friends.

   For example, if your program is called `myprog`, you could do

   ```
   openssl aes-256-cbc -e -in myprog -out mycode
   ```

   which will ask you for an encryption password (twice)
   and then write an encrypted copy of your program to `mycode`. 
   (You can leave out the `-e` (encrypt); it’s the default.) 
   You could then write a script like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   clear_prog=$(mktemp)
   chmod 700 "$clear_prog"
   openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in /path/to/mycode -out "$clear_prog"
   "$clear_prog" "$@"
   rm "$clear_prog"
   ```

   (using `-d` to decrypt.)  There’s still a risk that `root`
   could make a copy of your program when somebody decrypts it.

Comment: Wow! Thanx. I know that `root` can brake it , but still I think it's will work very good for me!. I need to read some books about Linux SCRIPTING :) . And this is great that in the KERNEL included some things that I can encrypt the stuff . And I need to rea `chmod` `openssl` manuals ...

Comment: It is works , now i need to learn how to use scripts to combone `locate` command and `openssl` encryption .

Answer (score 3):

The tricky part about your requirement is that you also want to prevent root from running it. Basically, a root user can do whatever they want on a system, after all, they're supposed to. A root user without this ability is like a security guard or janitor without keys to the building they work at.

However, preventing other users from running the executable can be achieved by `chmod`, provided that you have the ownership of the file in question: `chmod 700 /some/executable/file`. This gives the owner of the file (the executable) all permissions (read/write/execute) and none to the other users on the system. While it is intuitive to think that one only would need to remove the execute-permission, a user would still be able to copy the executable into their own directory, and then make it executable again. Therefore read permission will also have to be removed.

Comment: It would be a strange world in which *root* was able to "revoke" its own powers, which is essentially what OP wants to achieve. That'd be like a God trying to diminish her own omnipotence. The solution to OP's problem is to manage users and permissions correctly. Someone must be *root*, so the sensitive application can be installed in the first place. All other users should be regular users with specific permissions as required.

Comment: We live in a strange world.  In Windows, the administrator cannot read users’ private files without taking ownership of them, and even the administrator has trouble with files owned by SYSTEM or TrustedInstaller.  I’ve used Windows systems using file servers that did not allow users to change permissions on their own files.  On some of the new-fangled Unixes (e.g., SELinux), you can even restrict the power of `root`.  And then, see my answer.

Comment: thanx , I will try it together with OpenSSL encryption - Maybe I need to found it , in the Kernel and see what is that ^_^ . Damn, it's all is so diffucult , so many rules , Windows was a MORE simplest :( .

Answer (score 1):

> I want to prevent other users, including root, from using an application that I have installed.

Setting the owner and owning group of the file properly, as well as its `chmod` will prevent undesired users other than `root` from executing the file.  Note that if other users can read the file, but not execute it, they can still copy it and change the `x` bit on their own copy, so you have to disable `r` permission with `x` permission if you want to prevent execution.

You can't prevent execution by `root` with the above mechanism, though, as `root` can `chmod` any file and also alter the owner and owning group to anything.  The only way to absolutely prevent `root` from executing a file is for it not to be on the system at all.

You can come close to this by storing the executable in an encrypted volume, and unlocking the volume right before you invoke the executable and closing the volume immediately thereafter.  However, a `root` process can read the executing image of any other process via `/proc`, so it's theoretically possible for another `root` process to copy the executable from what is in memory.  I am not sure if it's possible to alter this behavior of Linux with a kernel compile option, if it is, then this may be something to consider.

If you have untrusted people logging on as `root`, or untrusted processes running as `root`, you really have to solve those problems instead.  You could look into virtualization and cordon off the untrusted section of your system in its own VM.

Comment: Yeah , it`s not good when root can be - badguy :( . But that is my situation , - machine is mine , but sometimes it's has a strange habbits , and I hell no idead how to check if my machine hacked or not - coz' I am newbie, but in ur community I found the solution :) .